# android viewmodel tab fragment

Tags: android, tabs, viewmodel

I created a new projets with AndroidStudio -> Tabbed Activity.
This activity creates 2 tab with textview. At the init the tabs are initialized with the index.

In the MainActivity there is a floating button which just produces a snackbar. I would like to use this fab action to change the tabbed textview text.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
    val viewPager: ViewPager = binding.viewPager
    viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
    val tabs: TabLayout = binding.tabs
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = binding.fab

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
         // here I would like to do an action to change the fragment text through the viewmodel
    }
}
```

}

and PageViewModel:

```
class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val text: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
    "Hello world from section: $it"
}

// The current score
private val _score = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val score: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _score

init {
    _score.value = 0
    Log.i("PageViewModel", "PageViewModel created!")
}

/** Methods for updating the UI **/
fun onInc() {
    _score.value = (_score.value)?.plus(1)
}


fun setIndex(index: Int) {
    _index.value = index
}
```

}

I am stuck with binding ...
Do you have any suggestion?

Best regards
Mich

Answer (score 0):

The issue around binding was because I used a template to pass the activity to the viewModel. So the instance pass inside the mainActivity was not the same as the instances passed inside the fragments. So I removed the template inside the fragments.
I guess an alternate solution would be to use the .getParent() inside the fragment to be able to use the template.
A little bit tricky but I must use an external library so I can not use classic examples...